# why stop() function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: jquery

I wrote this jQuery code, but when i tried to stop the animated elements while it is returning to its original position (using Callback function),it didn't responded, but it become slower !! .
I am using jquery-1.6.4 version

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#right").click(function () {
            $(".theDiv0").animate({ left: "800px" }, 2000, "swing", returnToLeft);
            $(".theDiv1").animate({ left: "800px" }, 2000, "linear", returnToLeft);
        });
        function returnToLeft() {
            $(".theDiv0").animate({ left: "10px" }, 2000, "swing");
            $(".theDiv1").animate({ left: "10px" }, 2000, "linear");
        }

        $("#stop").click(function () {
            $(".theDiv0,.theDiv1").stop();
           });
    });
</script>
```

Any Suggestion/Solution ??

Comment: Your code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/hLbE7/. Is there other script running animations which are interefering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.stop(true)`

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for further informations. If I'm right, this should really stop the animation.

Comment: @Daok just a typo, thanks James for fixing. I meant, he should change the params of his `stop()` by adding a "true" to it. Default is false as you can see in the docs.

Comment: If what I suspect is happening is right, this should work as well, stopping all queued animations.

Answer (score 1):

I am only seeing the described issue if `right` is clicked twice, which would queue up multiple `animate`s.  You can fix this by calling stop prior to each animate in case some other animation is already in progress:

```
    $("#right").click(function () {
        $(".theDiv0").stop().animate({ left: "800px" }, 2000, "swing", returnToLeft);
        $(".theDiv1").stop().animate({ left: "800px" }, 2000, "linear", returnToLeft);
    });
    function returnToLeft() {
        $(".theDiv0").stop().animate({ left: "10px" }, 2000, "swing");
        $(".theDiv1").stop().animate({ left: "10px" }, 2000, "linear");
    }
```

Or by only starting the animation if one isn't already in progress, using `.is(":animated")`.

As you have it now, the animation should stop once you have clicked `stop` as many times as `right` was clicked.