# jQuery stop doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, animation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main_img_1").hover(function (){
        $(this).stop().css({"background-size": '110% 110%'}, 200);
        $(".mainimgover").stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: '+=468px'}, 400);
        $(".mainimgover2").stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: '+=468px'}, 500);
    }).mouseout(function (){
        $(this).stop().css({"background-size": '100% 100%'}, 200);
        $(".mainimgover").stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: '-=468px'}, 400);
        $(".mainimgover2").stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: '-=468px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

I tried with `stop(true)`, `stop(true,true)` but no result. When you hover and leave before the animation end, the next animations are screwed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010564/why-stop-function-doesnt-work-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add some delay in animation to avoid flicker issue.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: No i don't need that. If the user moouseout before the animation end it still cause a bug.

Comment: However, after hours of different tries i did it on my own.